# Странное поведение lubuntu (16.04) при запуске shell-скрипта

Tags: ubuntu, shell

Вот у меня есть скрипт, при дубльтыке на который вылазит подобное окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажимаю "Запустить в терминале" и открывается терминал в том месте, откуда запущен скрипт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему же сам скрипт не запускается? Что я мог сломать и как это починить? Если в этом же терминале прописать запуск скрипта вручную, то он запустится без проблем. Я пробовал устанавливать разные терминалы и везде тот же результат. С правами запуска тоже всё в порядке.

Comment: наверно, перевод текста на кнопке не совсем адекватен происходящему. почему я так думаю? потому что по умолчанию сразу же по окончании работы вашего скрипта окно эмулятора терминала **закроется**. и какого-то универсального решения для того, чтобы окно **любой** из множества реализаций эмуляторов терминала не закрывалось, [насколько мне известно, не существует](http://askubuntu.com/q/46627/416190).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы меня наверное не правильно поняли. Эта кнопка в убунте и минте именно запускает скрипт в терминале! А в лубунте почему-то открывает терминал и на этом всё.

Comment: Возможно проблема даже не в лубунте, а в том, что я примонтировал к ней раздел /home от минта и она подхватила какие-то лишние настройки, хотя и не факт.

Comment: UPD: Только что зашёл под гостевым сеансом, создал тестовый скрипт, запустил через эту кнопку и он выполнился! Значит проблема 100% в каких-то пользовательских настройках/ассоциациях. Узнать бы в каких...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему тем, что удалил все файлы в ~/.config

К сожалению, точной причины ошибки так и не понял.